# Wrong MD5 sum on every download of Ubuntu [12.04, 64bit]

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, md5sum

I've been having quite an adventure trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit edition.

My computer has a core i5 2500k processor, 16GB of RAM, and 500GB of hard drive space.

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit a few times with a bootable USB, but after hitting install, I would be shown scrolling text which would eventually freeze and not allow me to do anything.

I tried a couple of times, making a new USB each time. I presumed that perhaps I got a bad download, so I checked the MD5 and it was not correct. I downloaded it again from the official download page, again a wrong MD5. I even downloaded it from the torrent link (the alternate) and AGAIN was given an incorrect MD5.

At this point, I checked my download of Linux Mint to see if maybe my MD5 sum program was, somehow, wrong about my Ubuntu downloads, and was given the correct MD5 there.

FWIW, the install of Linux Mint would freeze as well, even though it had a verified MD5. However it installed in a VM just fine.

Oh also, I downloaded and created a live USB of 11.10, verified MD5 and all, and still no dice.

Any ideas? My friend mentioned it could be the USB device at fault here. It is a PNY Flash drive.

Comment: You should test the written installation media on the computer on which you're installing it, using [this method](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html). Please note that while that says "Check disc for defects" it applies equally to USB flash drives and any other installation media. Once you have done this, please **edit your question** to include the results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're inserting your USB stick in a USB 2.0 port. The newer USB 3.0 ports can sometimes cause problems.